# Google code downloading source

Tags: mercurial, google-code

This might be an extremely stupid question, but for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to download this:

http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/source/browse/#hg%253Fstate%253Dclosed

There is nothing under the "downloads" tab. And when I try to "clone" it using my terminal it says "HG command not found".

Any ideas??

Comment: What are you trying to download on that page? Are you trying to download xmpp?

Comment: Yep, the whole framework and examples found of the source tab.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

hg is the executable for Mercurial, you're going to need to download and install [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org).

Once you have it installed you can use it to clone the project:

```
hg clone https://xmppframework.googlecode.com/hg/ xmppframework
```

Comment: Once you clone it, it should create a directory within  your current working directory.

Comment: It is a command line based VCS software. If you want a GUI, for Mac OSX there is MacHg, found here: http://www.jasonfharris.com/machg/. For windows I am not quite sure.