# Download Google Code in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, svn, google-code

I want to download zip file of the project located in code.google.com from Ubuntu. I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

And I also referred [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107308/how-do-i-use-git-with-google-code-on-ubuntu%5D), but still I haven't get any output. And also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132255/google-code-downloading-source)

Please help me out. I have sucked with this problem and can't go ahead in my work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have installed git. If you don't have installed git yet, try it this way in a console:

```
sudo apt-get install -y git
```

After that you should be able to download the sources like this:

```
git clone https://path/to/repo
```

That special repo you are linking uses svn so you need to install svn:

```
sudo apt-get install -y svn
```

The download works like this:

```
svn checkout http://android-mt-tutorials.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ android-mt-tutorials-read-only
```

By the way it is also explained here:

https://code.google.com/p/android-mt-tutorials/source/checkout

Comment: It is giving me an error as : fatal: https://code.google.com/p/android-mt-tutorials/source/browse/#svn%2Ftags%2FFallingSnow-2/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?

Comment: Whats wrong here?? I want to download [this](https://code.google.com/p/android-mt-tutorials/source/browse/#svn%2Ftags%2FFallingSnow-2) project....

Comment: I have SVN installed on my system .... and please help me to chat.. i am enable to chat :(

Comment: You may need to refresh the site for chatting

Comment: I did it... i logged out and again logged in.. Even i close browser and relaunched it.. Still it sowing you need 20 reputation to chat even though I am having 21 rep...